# Есть ли какой нить веб эмулятор андроида?

Tags: android, html, веб-программирование

Нужна возможность запускать онлайн apk (андроидовские приложения). Есть ли такие эмуляторы ?

Comment: есть приложение для Google Chrome, позволяющее запускать свои .apk файлы - называется ARC Welder. в пользовании вроде несложная

Comment: Нужно ток для IE

Comment: Не знаю как онлайн... а вот есть прога такая как `BlueStacks` там вроде можно запускать все `apk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут можно: https://www.manymo.com/, но это платно, не думаю, что существуют бесплатные.

Answer (score 1):

У Intel есть подобный сервис https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/android/app-testing хотя сам пока не пользовался и подробностей не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

ARC Welder — расширение, которое поможет запустить Android-приложения в Chrome
[ссылка](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn)

Answer (score 1):

https://appetize.io - вот тут можно, 100 минут в месяц бесплатно.